# Resources and Codename One

Tags: codenameone

I am using Codename One and I want to insert a lot of html pages in my app and then load them in a WebView. I want to insert html files in resources. How can I insert files in resources, maybe by using GUI builder data? What is the code to load the html files in WebView?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this. If you can package every individual file into a single file you can use something like this:

1. put the `test.html` in default package
2. create   `WebBrowser webBrowser = new WebBrowser();` and add to your form
3. `webBrowser.setUrl("jar:///test.html")`

If you need a complex HTML/CSS/JavaScript hierarchy then you can place all your files into the root html package (`src/html`).
Then open an HTML file from within the html package using code like this:

```
try {
    browserComponent.setURLHierarchy("/htmlFile.html");
} catch(IOException err) {
    ...
}
```

Notice that the path is relative to the html directory and starts with `/` but inside the HTML files you should use
relative (not absolute) paths.

> The build server will `tar` the entire content of that package and add
>   an `html.tar` file into the native package. This `tar` is seamlessly
>   extracted on the device when you actually need the resources and only
>   with new application versions (not on every launch).

From the [manual](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/components.html).

As a sidenote the resource files do support adding arbitrary data files but the hierarchies solution is a better approach.

Comment: I added two other options for the answer

Comment: I use a WebBrowser component with this code in my StateMachine.java file: 
 @Override
    protected boolean onMainItem1() {
        String baseUrl = "jar:///Prova.html"; 
        findWebBrowser().setURL(baseUrl);
        return true;
    }

this code works in simulator but doesn't in build. I want to insert a site in my app (a complex HTML/CSS/JavaScript hierarchy).